# Upgrade to Civicrm 5.5.3 fails

Tags: upgrade

Error message when I run 
http://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1

Does anyone have any ideas?

Initialization Error

Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => simpleHandler
        )

```
[code] => -18
[message] => DB Error: no such table
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => SHOW COLUMNS FROM civicrm_domain LIKE 'config_backend' [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'edifideo_wp398.civicrm_domain' doesn't exist]
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] => SHOW COLUMNS FROM civicrm_domain LIKE 'config_backend' [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'edifideo_wp398.civicrm_domain' doesn't exist]
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such table" code=-18 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::simpleHandler prefix="" info="SHOW COLUMNS FROM civicrm_domain LIKE 'config_backend' [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'edifideo_wp398.civicrm_domain' doesn't exist]"]
```

)

Comment: does the table exists edifideo_wp398.civicrm_domain?

Comment: It seems odd that the upgrade would attempt to update a database that didn't contain `civicrm_domain`, which is a core table.  Per Pradeep's comment - could you confirm that the `civicrm_domain` table exists?  Also, please confirm that `edifideo_wp398` is the database that contains CiviCRM?  Finally, please let us know if CiviCRM and WordPress are in the same database or separated?  If you're not sure how to check these, come ask on https://chat.civicrm.org or reply (with a comment) asking specific questions.